# How to find all rows that have a subfield in nested records? PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb

All my records are structured like this:

```
{ 'name': 'John Doe',
  'atributes' : {
       'alive' : {'start':15816412115, 'end':1516186131 },
       'job'   : 'developer',
       'title' : 'senior',
   }
},
{ 'name': 'John Cena',
  'atributes-2017' : {
       'alive' : {'start':15816412115, 'end':1516186131 },
       'job'   : 'dancer',
   }
}
```

How select only the records that have a subfield **title** in atributes and atributes-2017:

I tried with this:

```
clients.find({'*': {'title': {'$exists': True }  }})
```

Comment: Do you only have `atributes` and `atributes-2017` or is this changing? If not maybe this will work:
```clients.find({ $or: [ { "atributes":  { "title": {$exists: true } }}, { "atributes-2017":  { "title": {$exists: true } }} ]})```

Comment: atributes may change, this is just an example

Comment: Just curious, what is the reason to keep varying fields?

Comment: I don't know who started this and the reason behind, but i have find a way....This can't be changed at the moment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below query will be helpful:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      docs: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      docs: {
        $map: {
          input: "$docs",
          as: "d",
          in: {
            $objectToArray: "$$d"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$docs"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "docs.v.title": {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $arrayToObject: "$docs"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayGroundLink](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UvrJeKT2tz8)

My suggestion is, not to keep varying fields. You should keep same fields across all the documents and add extra information as the sub-fields (not in the field name). Like below:

```
{ 'name': 'John Doe',
  'atributes' : {
       'alive' : {'start':15816412115, 'end':1516186131 },
       'job'   : 'developer',
       'title' : 'senior',
   }
},
{ 'name': 'John Cena',
  'atributes' : {
       'alive' : {'start':15816412115, 'end':1516186131 },
       'job'   : 'dancer',
       'year'  : 2017
   }
}
```

Otherwise, it will become difficult to query.